# Import skflow on a Windows machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

I am trying to import skflow on my Windows PC. I have already install and used Anaconda on Python (3.5). I have no trouble to use tensorflow but when I want to use skflow I get the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-04faecc7c0de> in <module>()
      8 import tensorflow as tf
      9 from tensorflow.contrib import learn
---> 10 from tensorflow.contrib import skflow

ImportError: cannot import name 'skflow'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow.contrib import learn as skflow
```

FYI, skflow is not any special package/module/... It's an alias for tensorflow.contrib.learn which is in 'sklearn' style.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this answer is not correct, as for your suggestion about skyflow being an alias, I don't think it's correct. 
FYI, I'm stuck on this tutorial: https://blog.socialcops.com/engineering/machine-learning-python/
these are the parts that are not working:
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.contrib import skflow
    tf_clf_dnn = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[20, 40, 20], n_classes=2, batch_size=256, steps=1000, learning_rate=0.05)
    tf_clf_dnn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    tf_clf_dnn.score(X_test, y_test)

Comment: That blog was posted in July'16. TensorFlow has changed since then, please refer [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/). You are missing 'feature_columns' argument while initializing the classifier.

Comment: `>>> from tensorflow.contrib import learn as skflow; help(skflow.DNNClassifier.__init__)`

Comment: help(skflow.DNNClassifier.__init__) 
this helped me very well. It seems that also the init parameters are changed, "batch_size=256, steps=1000, learning_rate=0.05" these are not accepted anymore. Anyway reason that I choose to follow that tutorial is that I thought is a recent article, I didn't know that it will change so fast.